# icons not showing up in firefox without "www." before domain

Tags: firefox, icons, opencart, font-awesome

I'm using OpenCart for my site. The icons fail to appear when you visit `example.com` but they do appear if you visit `www.example.com`.

Any ideas what is going on here?

I have just edited `config.php` file and removed `www.` and it works for *naked* domain but the icons do not load

```
// HTTP

define('HTTP_SERVER', 'http://example.com');

define('HTTP_CATALOG', 'http://example.com');

define('HTTP_IMAGE', 'http://example.com/image');

define('HTTP_ADMIN', 'http://example.com/admin');
```

Answer (score 2):

I would redirect all non www traffic to www. This should take care of your issue with icons. It'll also prevent possible SEO issues as a result of duplicate content/pages.

If you have an apache server add a redirect to your .htaccess.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me:

- Go into the config.php file (please backup your file first) in the main directory of your OpenCart installation.
- Under //HTTP (lines 5-8 for me), edit

lines:

```
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'http://example.com/shop/');
define('HTTP_CATALOG', 'http://example.com/shop/');
define('HTTP_IMAGE', 'http://example.com/shop/image/');
define('HTTP_ADMIN', 'http://example.com/shop/admin/');
```

to read:

```
define('HTTP_SERVER', '/shop/');
define('HTTP_CATALOG', '/shop/');
define('HTTP_IMAGE', '/shop/image/');
define('HTTP_ADMIN', '/shop/admin/');
```

.

Depending on your installation, I'm sure this could cause some problem somewhere I just haven't found it...  yet...  (maybe someone else could correct me -- I really don't mind; I like to learn).

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

Add to .htaccess file this line: `Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "your-domain.com"`

Change `"your-domain.com"` required by the url.

If in our configuration file use: `define ('HTTP_SERVER' 'http://example.com/);`

Then place: `Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://www.example.com/"`

I tested this in opencart 2.0.